# Relational Queries In parse.com (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I found example in parse.com. I have 2 objects : Post and Comment, in the Comment objects have a collumn: "parent" pointer to Post obj and I want to join them:

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Comment");
// Include the post data with each comment
query = query.Include("parent");
query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> comments = t.Result;
        // Comments now contains the last ten comments, and the "post" field
        // contains an object that has already been fetched.  For example:
    foreach (var comment in comments)
    {

        // This does not require a network access.
        string o= comment.Get<string>("content");
        Debug.Log(o);
        try {
            string post = comment.Get<ParseObject>("parent").Get<string>("title");
            Debug.Log(post);


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.Log(ex);  
        }
    }

});
```

It worked!
And then, I have 2 objects: User and Gamescore, in the Gamescore objects have a collumn: "playerName" pointer to Post obj I want join them too:

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("GameScore");
        query.Include ("playerName");
        query.FindAsync ().ContinueWith (t =>{
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> result = t.Result;
            foreach (var item in result) {
                Debug.Log("List score: ");
                int score = item.Get<int>("score");
                Debug.Log(score);
                try {
                    var obj = item.Get<ParseUser>("playerName");
                    string name = obj.Get<string>("profile");
                    //string name = item.Get<ParseUser>("playerName").Get<string>("profile");

                    Debug.Log(name);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Debug.Log(ex);  
                }
            }
        });
```

but It isn't working, Please help me!

Comment: Help Me. Please. Anybody.?

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you do the following like you did your first example:

```
query = query.Include ("playerName");
```

you just have -

```
query.Include ("playerName");
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to ensure that your ParseUser object is properly fetched. ie:

```
var obj = item.Get<ParseUser>("playerName");
Task t = obj.FetchIfNeededAsync();
while (!t.IsCompleted) yield return null;
```

Then you can do this without worrying:

```
string name = obj.Get<string>("profile");
```

But that will be another potential request to Parse, which is unfortunate. It seems that  `query.Include ("playerName")` isn't properly working in the Unity version of Parse?

Comment: Thank you so much!
but what shoud I do to do that? because I wanna get data from User object!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're supposed to use multi-level includes for this, like `.Include("parent.playerName")` in your first query.